# How to pass Delphi empty string to com visible .net assembly

Tags: .net, string, delphi, comvisible

I have a C# assembly that contains a ComVisible class with a method taking 2 string parameters. I have registered the assembly and imported it using Delphi XE2's "Import Component" command.

The C# interface looks like this:

```
[ComVisible(true),
 Guid("132D7742-D86A-49E4-81FD-D804E6872475"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IResourceManager
{        
    int AddResource(string guid, string address);
}
```

The imported Delphi interface looks like this:

```
IResourceManager= dispinterface
['{132D7742-D86A-49E4-81FD-D804E6872475}']
function AddResource(const Guid: WideString; const address: WideString): Integer; dispid 1610743809;
end;
```

Here is an example of how the code is called from Delphi:

```
procedure TResourceManager.AddResource(const Guid, Address: String);
var
  ResourceManager: IResourceManager;
begin
  ResourceManager := CoResourceManager.Create;
  ResourceManager.AddResource(Guid, Address);
end;
```

Everything works 100% as long as I don't pass empty strings to the method from my Delphi application. When I do I get a the following error on the .Net side:

*InvalidVariant was detected
Message: An invalid VARIANT was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss.*

Ideally I want to be able to call the method from the Delphi side with an empty string '' and on the .Net side do a *string.IsNullOrEmpty(guid)* to check for this condition. So far all I have been able to do is to pass *#0* to the method instead of '' from Delphi but on the .Net side the value becomes *"\0"* which is neither null nor empty.

What is the correct approach to deal with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, my answer was deleted by somebody, and it seems that it wasn't the problem anyway. But to all, that try to solve this riddle, we made sure that really a COM-compatible WideString is passed, so this cannot be the problem here.

Comment: just a guess, because I never wrote com server in c#, maybe you need to declare the string variables in c# as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]? and the Delphi needs `stdcall` convention added to `AddResource`.